# PreCalc problem about high tide?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$y=3+4\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{5.7}(x-2)\right)$$

$x$ is the time in hours after midnight

What time did the first high tide occur today?

How deep was the water at the time?

When will the second high tide occur today?

Comment: It would be good if you could also include your attempt. Do you have any understanding of amplitude?

Comment: Yes, the sinusoid axis is at 3, and the amplitude is 4.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\cos[(\frac{\pi}{5.7})(x-2)]$? Do you know what is meant by "high tide" in the model? Do you know what $y$ is?

Comment: No, it's just cos(pi/5.7).

Comment: Can you confirm that the way I edited your equation is really how it's written? If not, can you point out what's different?

Comment: That surprises me, because $\cos(\frac{\pi}{5.7})$ is just a constant, which means that the expression on the right-hand side is a linear equation [$m=4\cos(\frac{\pi}{5.7})$ and $b=3-8\cos(\frac{\pi}{5.7})$], which doesn't match my experience with tides at all :)

Comment: It must mean $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5.7}(x-2)\right)$. Otherwise it would make no sense and the tide would increase without limit. In other words, the earth would be consumed by ever increasing oceans that will eventually take up the whole known universe. unlikely..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean:
$$y=3+4\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{5.7}(x-2)\right)$$

Then, high tide occurs when the value of the $\cos$ function is equal to $1$, which makes the equation:
$$y_{max} = 3+4(1) = 7$$
This is the maximum depth of the water.

What value of $x$ makes the $\cos$ function equal to $1$?  Well, $\cos(2k\pi)=1$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.  So, we want to solve:
$$\dfrac{\pi}{5.7}(x-2) = 2k\pi$$
$$(x-2) = 11.4k$$
$$x = 11.4k + 2$$
We pick the value of $k$ that minimizes this expression (we want the soonest time after midnight), so we pick $k=0$.  Thus, we have:
$$x = 2$$
Or, $2:00\,\text{am}$.

For the second high tide, we increment $k$ by $1$:
$$x = 11.4+2 = 13.4$$
Or, $1:24\,\text{pm}$.